# No such module 'GoogleMobileAds'

Tags: ios, admob, xcode12, google-mobile-ads

After upgrading Google Mobile SDK 8.0 via Cocoapods, Xcode throws me error 'No such Module 'GoogleMobileAds'.
I did my search but nothing helped me so far.

I already did these steps:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
rm -rf Pods
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
pod deintegrate
pod setup
pod install
Also removed Podfile, Podfile.lock and xcworkspace file before pod install
```

I am sharing some screenshots for you to help me what I am doing wrong.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a known issue, my specific scenario was for flutter, but I guess the concept is the same just set the version back to

```
 pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 7.69.0'
```

That did the trick for me.
You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45281715/how-to-change-the-version-of-a-cocoapods-dependency/45322760#45322760).